# AWS loadbalancer response

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, request, response

I am using AWS application load balancer. My requests are come from load balancer but response is not going through load balancer. it is going through instance public IP. 
Please suggest any configuration change require in load balancer or something else I need to do.

Comment: How did you determine that response is not going through Load Balancer?

Comment: You should probably answer the comment here

Answer (score 0):

All request and response are taken care by loadbalancer.You can find your IP from given load balancer url. If that ip is configured with some domain name,then that domain name will be shown. All Response will be going through domain ip configured at loadbalancer.